# Javascript não funciona no github pages

Tags: javascript, github

EU consigo rodar meu site no localhost. Mas no github pages não funciona a parte JS.

index.html:

`<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

código: https://github.com/YannHyaric/Amazon-Copia

site:https://yannhyaric.github.io/Amazon-Copia/

Comment: Você deve fazer o _build_ para funcionar no gh-pages.

Comment: Mesmo fazendo build, não aparece nada na pagina

Comment: Nenhuma pergunta pode depender dee links externos, e se funciona localmente, provavelmente não está no escopo do site. Alternativamente, se acreditar que o post está no escopo, basta [edit] o post e trazer um [mcve] do problema para reavaliação. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo visto você fez quase tudo que é necessário, tenta isto no seu package.json

```
"scripts": {
 ...
 "predeploy": "yarn build",
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

depois roda `yarn run deploy`, eu não entendi o porque do `src/index.html`, pra fazer o deploy de react?